# How to get next resultset in Cassandra DB

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, cql, datastax-java-driver

Table contains more than 100,000 rows. I am trying to get the total row count. I do not want to use async.

```
Statement statement = session.prepare("SELECT user_id from table");
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement);
int count = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching()
```

I am getting 5000 rows from the above. Is it possible to iterate and get the next 5000 resultsets till 100,000 so I can sum up the rows to get the total count.
I am getting timeout error when using `session.execute(statement.setPageSize(100000));`

- DSE - 6.8.9
- Cql - 3.4.5
- Cassandra - 4.0.0.681
- Java driver - 4.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to modify your database query? If so, you could modify your query to `SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM table` and then you will only need to look at one row of data.

If not, it looks like you need to use the `.fetchMoreResults()` method to get the next results. I see you don't want to use async at all. That can be avoided by just calling `.get()`

```
Statement statement = session.prepare("SELECT user_id from table");
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement);
int count = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
while (!resultSet.isExhausted()) {
    resultSet = resultSet.fetchMoreResults().get();
    count += resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
}
```

Full disclosure; I have not used DSE before, this is just what I could glean from their [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSet.html). Things that will need to be checked still, that I can think of:

1. should the condition be checking `isExhausted()` or `isFullyFetched()`?
2. does `getAvailableWithoutFetching()` return the number of results in the current page, or the total number of results fetched so far? I've assumed the former, but if it is the latter then `count` should just be set based on the last `resultSet`'s available size, instead of being added to for each page

EDIT: I see you have version [4.6.1](https://javadoc.io/static/com.datastax.oss/java-driver-core/4.6.1/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/cql/ResultSet.html), ok. It seems like the `pagingState()` is worth looking into.

```
Statement statement = session.prepare("SELECT user_id from table");
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(statement);
int count = resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
ByteBuffer pagingState = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
while (pagingState != null) {
    statement = statement.copy(pagingState);
    resultSet = session.execute(statement);
    pagingState = resultSet.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
    count += resultSet.getAvailableWithoutFetching();
}
return count;
```

Comment: I have java veriosn 4.6 which does not support fetchMoreResults and isExhausted

Comment: @Gvtha I've updated my answer to include another solution that I believe will work for you.

Comment: while loop is running indefinitely since there is no updation for pagingState inside the loop. When the pagingState will become null

Comment: You're right. I've updated once again.